# CSS transparent border

Tags: html, css, border

I am trying to make transparent border. I tried `transparent` and `rgba`.

[Example fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/u0macpe4/2/)

```css
.menu-item {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 5px 10px !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent !important; 
  //border-bottom:5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #1a1a1b;
  color: #ccc;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu-item">Disabled</li>
  <li class="menu-item">English</li>
  <li class="menu-item">German</li>
  <li class="menu-item">Spanish</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Both will create a fully transparent border, so what's the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want border-bottom you may use the following code:

```
.menu-item {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 5px 10px !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #fff !important; 
  /* bottom:5px solid rgba(0,0,0,0); */
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #1a1a1b;
  }
```

You can however achieve the same by simply using

```
margin-bottom:5px;
```

And removing :
    margin:0 !important;

https://jsfiddle.net/u0macpe4/14/

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just use margin instead of border - your border is transparent but you applied a background so that shows through.

A little tip also - `!important` should be used as a last resort when you are unable to override some plugin's inline style - the way you are using it liberally, your code will soon become unmaintainable

```css
.menu-item {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #1a1a1b;
  color: #ccc;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu-item">Disabled</li>
  <li class="menu-item">English</li>
  <li class="menu-item">German</li>
  <li class="menu-item">Spanish</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the `background-clip` in order to avoid the background to extend to your borders:

```css
.menu-item {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 5px 10px !important;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #1a1a1b;
  background-clip:padding-box; /* add this*/
  color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu-item">Disabled</li>
  <li class="menu-item">English</li>
  <li class="menu-item">German</li>
  <li class="menu-item">Spanish</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not see the border with `rgba` because you set `0` to `opacity` what mean do not see

please set `opacity:>0` in `rgba` to white color use `(255,255,255,1)`(`opacity`  as you want)

```css
.menu-item {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 0 !important;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  //border-bottom: 5px solid transparent !important; 
  border-bottom:5px solid rgba(255,255,255, 0.9);
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #1a1a1b;
  color: #ccc;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu-item">Disabled</li>
  <li class="menu-item">English</li>
  <li class="menu-item">German</li>
  <li class="menu-item">Spanish</li>
</ul>
```

**Note!**

do not use `!important` if do not really needed:https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Answer (score -1):

```
.menu-item {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 5px 10px !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  border-bottom:5px solid white;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #1a1a1b;
  color: #ccc;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  white-space: nowrap;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

try this